# Guava Cache for Primitive Value

Tags: guava

I have initialized a cache as

`cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();`

Now I am adding a key with primitive int value

Will this key be removed after 30 minutes if I am updating the key with same primitive value

Comment: Yes.  This has nothing to do with primitives; it'll be boxed and everything will work the same from there.

Comment: Just to further clarify Louis's answer, you can't have a key with a primitive int value. The generic type system only works on Objects. So you'll end up having to work with Integer keys.

Comment: So it will internally change int value to Integer ? Because  I have an use case where I am adding int value which gets disappear intermidently from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Java primitives are able to be turned into objects by something called boxing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

As the name suggests, the primitive is wrapped in an object (the metaphorical box) and then the variable it turned into a standard reference to an object.

This has some negative performance implications in some cases but does allow you to treat primitives like standard object.

Instead of `int` you can reference the cached objects as `Integer` which is a proper class.